# How can I list successful jenkins builds using a groovy script in a deploy job?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have a Jenkins deploy job that copies artifacts from a build job. In my deploy job, I am using a groovy script (see below) in an Extensible Choice parameter to present a list of successful builds from that build job in a drop-down. I would like to enhance the groovy script to list only successful builds from that build job. How can I do this?

```
def builds = []
def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(JOB-NAME)
job.builds.each {
    def build = it
    it.badgeActions.each {
        builds.add(build.displayName[1..-1])
    }
}
builds.unique();
```

Comment: What is the format for `JOB-NAME` and how can I derive it from my system?  I've tried several things but can't get anything to work...

Answer (score 11):

I managed to get it figured out ... see code snippet below

```
def builds = []

def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(JOB-NAME)
job.builds.each {
    def build = it
    if (it.getResult().toString().equals("SUCCESS")) {
        it.badgeActions.each {
             builds.add(build.displayName[1..-1])
        }
    }
}    
builds.unique();
```

Comment: `job.builds.findAll{ it.result.toString()=='SUCCESS' && it.badgeActions }.collect{ it.displayName[1..-1] }`

Comment: Thanks, much more concise ... will try your solution out too

Comment: much more efficient to use `hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS == it.result` instead of converting to a String

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins 2.289.2 the working code is as following:

```
def builds = []

def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(JOB-NAME)
job.builds.each {
    if (it.result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS) {
        builds.add(it.displayName[1..-1])
    }
}

return builds
```

The difference is in absence of **badgeActions**, which shows only builds made before the Jenkins upgrade.