# How to retrieve build_id of latest successful build in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

Generally, to get the artifact of the latest successful build, I do a `wget` on the below URL:

http://jenkins.com/job/job_name/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/artifact1/jenkins.txt

Is there a way, I can do a `wget` on `lastSuccessfulBuild` and get a `build_id` like below?

```
build_id=`wget http://jenkins.p2pcredit.local/job/job_name/lastSuccessfulBuild`
```

Comment: If you're looking for a groovy script checkout this answer and it's comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27362178/316343

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, there is a way and it is pretty straightforward:

```
$ build_id=`wget -qO- jenkins_url/job/job_name/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber`
$ echo $build_id
131 # that's my build number
```

Comment: How does it work over https ? It keeps on giving me `Unable to establish SSL connection`.

Comment: The simplest way should be to add `--no-check-certificate` parameter to `wget`. Take a look at [HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html#HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options)

Comment: Be careful with this answer. If you want the value of `BUILD_ID` specifically, especially when using plugins that allow you to customize the build ID, this won't work, and neither will swapping out `buildNumber` for `buildID`

Comment: Is there a URL to: get the latest build and open it in browser?

Answer (score 7):

I think the best solution is using groovy with zero dependencies.

```
node {
    script{
        def lastSuccessfulBuildID = 0
        def build = currentBuild.previousBuild
        while (build != null) {
            if (build.result == "SUCCESS")
            {
                lastSuccessfulBuildID = build.id as Integer
                break
            }
            build = build.previousBuild
        }
        println lastSuccessfulBuildID
    }
}
```

You do not need specify jenkins_url or job_name etc to get last successful build id.
Then you could use it easily in all Jenkinsfile in repositories without useless configurations.

Tested on Jenkins v2.164.2

Comment: Would it be possible without jenkins file? It works fine in a "dsl script" but I'm trying it with a Groovy Script, inside the job. It does not work (`import jenkins.model.Jenkins` in `Execute Groovy script ` step). I know it's very basic but I'm lost. Maybe specifying the classpath?

Comment: I answer myself with [this reference](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin#Groovyplugin-GroovyScriptvsSystemGroovyScript)

Comment: This is only useful if you want the latest build of the job your in.  If you need the latest successful build of another project this wont work.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the DisplayName of the last successful job and not build number:

```
curl --user <username>:<tokenOrPassword> https://<url>/job/<job-name>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json | jq -r '.displayName'
```

Or in groovy

```
def buildName = Jenkins.instance.getItem('jobName').lastSuccessfulBuild.displayName
```

Answer (score 5):

I find very useful querying permalinks file inside Jenkins workspace.

This allows you, to not only get the last successful build, but also other builds Jenkins considers relevant.

You can see it's content adding this line in Build section, in Execute Shell panel:

```
cat ../../jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/permalinks
```

For example, in my case:

```
+ cat ../../jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/permalinks
lastCompletedBuild 56
lastFailedBuild 56
lastStableBuild 51
lastSuccessfulBuild 51
lastUnstableBuild -1
lastUnsuccessfulBuild 56
```

From there, you would want to parse the number of the last successful build, or any other provided by permalinks, you can do this running:

```
lastSuccesfulBuildId=$(cat ../../jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/permalinks | grep lastSuccessfulBuild | sed 's/lastSuccessfulBuild //')
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipeline script solution :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper           
def jResponse = httpRequest "https:/<yourjenkinsjoburlpath>/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber"
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jResponse.content)
echo "Status: ${json}"
```

jenkins console output:

```
HttpMethod: GET
URL: https://***/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber
Sending request to url: https://***/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Success code from [100‥399]
[Pipeline] echo
Status: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last successful build number using curl:

curl --user userName:password https://url/job/jobName/api/xml?xpath=/*/lastStableBuild/number

Comment: You can also pass a `token` in place of password and the above curl request will work to retrieve last stable build number (not build name). Tested on jenkins 2.190.2

Answer (score 1):

to get the job build number simply do:

def build_Number = Jenkins.instance.getItem('JobName').lastSuccessfulBuild.number

Comment: There is an error `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance`

Comment: Go to manage jenkins > In Process Script Approval and approve that Jenkins.model.JenkinsgetInstance