# Jenkins Pipeline-Copy artifact plugin- How to get build number of copied artifact

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

While copying artifacts from another project, How can I get build number of copied artifact in Jenkins pipeline.

For normal Jenkins job, env variable is set as `COPYARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER_${PROJECT_NAME}`, 
similarly is there any way we can get build number in pipeline?

Comment: A workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601108/jenkins-copy-artifact-parse-copied-build-id