# Running a specific diff command between files in two Jenkins builds

Tags: c++, c, jenkins, abi

I recently discovered `abidiff`; a tool that takes two binaries as input, and describes differences in ABI. This could prove useful to detect when ABI version numbers need to change.

Ideally we would integrate this into our Jenkins based CI, but I can't immediately see a straightforward way to run a command on a file in the current build and the corresponding file in the last successful build (ideally on the same branch).

I did play around with an `Exceute Shell` build step, but couldn't see an obvious way to get at the previous successful build number, from which I would eventually be able to get a path to the files I want to compare. Any suggestions/pointers on how to get this? There is the `GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT` environment variable, but this isn't much use as far as I can tell, as resolving the SHA to a file on disk would require resolving the SHA to the build number.

Comment: 1. Why is this tagged C/C++?

Comment: abidiff is a tool for C and/or C++

Comment: That shouldn't really matter. The act of running a diff is different from the file types it's being run on.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last successfull build like this (if you are using a pipeline)

```
import jenkins.model.*

def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('<jobname>')
def buildNumber = job.getLastSuccessfulBuild().getNumber()
sh "abidiff <my-file> ../builds/$buildNumber"
```

You might also want to take a look at: [How to retrieve build_id of latest successful build in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508603/how-to-retrieve-build-id-of-latest-successful-build-in-jenkins)

Or you might think about [archiveArtifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts)

Comment: Mmm, I had come across stuff like that, but we're not using pipelines unfortunately.

Comment: Have a look at the other stackoverflow link then. It uses only the shell.