# Dynamic parameter based on previous string parameter

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins I have a string parameter *HOST*. After this parameter I have a dynamic parameter *URL*. This parameter needs to be a concatenation of strings, including the previously defined *HOST* parameter.

I have been unable to find out how to do this.

The motivation for this is subsequent parameters will also use this *HOST* parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure I understand your requirement correctly: you have two parameters and the later one is depends on the value of the first one?

If it's so I think [plugin Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) is enough for this:

- Job configuration:

[image: parameter definition]
[image]

- Build with specified value:

[image: Build with specified value]

- Build result:

[image: Build result]

- If you change your `HOST` value at build, the `URL` will also changed.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Perfect - just the ticket

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 3):

The dynamic parameter plugin might not be the right choice for your task.
If you want the URL parameter to be updated according to the changes in the HOST parameter, you should consider using the [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin).

In your case, create a String parameter for the host, and an active choice reactive parameter for the url. this parameter reads the host and updates the url. example:

[image]

(you can find another example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42871619/947784)