# How to pass parameters from one promotion to another promotion in the same job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, promoted-builds

I am working in Jenkins. I have one job setup. In which I have 4 promotions like dev qa staging and prod. We have a choice parameter set in third promotion. And depending on the value selected in 3rd promotion I want to execute 4th promotion.Is there a way to pass parameters from 3rd promotion to 4th in the same job.

Comment: the promotion is a parameter? take a look at the answer for a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666321/how-can-i-get-all-build-numbers-of-particular-job-in-jenkins-using-groovy-script/42871619#42871619 let me know if it helped.

Comment: while approving third promotion approver selects one value for the choice parameter. That value of the parameter I want to pass to the next promotion.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear what you mean by promotion

Comment: After the job is built successfully.I have configured promotions to promote/deploy code in different environments.Through "promote builds when" checkbox in job configuration page.

Comment: @Saga Did you ever find a solution?