# Get other job's build git commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can one get some other job builds's git commit hash from another job using the pipeline?
I am looking for something like:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.Job)
     .filter { it.fullName.equals(params.theOtherJobNameSpecifiedViaParamByTheUser)[0]
     .getBuild(params.buildNoSpecifiedViaParamByTheUser)
     .getGitCommitHashOfTheSelectedBuild()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API for Jenkins either via XML or via JSON.

First get the URL you need:

**XML:** https://JENKINS-HOST/jenkins/job/JOB-NAME/job/JOB-BRANCH/BUILD-NUMBER/api/xml

**JSON:** https://JENKINS-HOST/jenkins/job/JOB-NAME/job/JOB-BRANCH/BUILD-NUMBER/api/json

Then parse the output.
I tend to use XPATH for the xml and also use shell.

```
def generate_xpath_url (URL, BRANCH) {
  branch = params.BRANCH_NAME
  jenkins_job_url = params.OTHER_JENKINS_JOB_URL
  remote_name = parse_git_remote_name(URL);
  url = other_jenkins_job_url + 'lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml?xpath=//refsremotes' + remote_name + branch + '/marked/SHA1'
  return url
}

...

lastBuildCommitUrl = generate_xpath_url(env.GIT_URL, env.GIT_BRANCH)
lastBuildNumberUrl = env.JOB_URL + 'lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber'
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
    credentialsId: 'SomeJenkinsNonUser',
    usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_API_USER',
    passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_API_PSW']])
{
    lastBuildCommit = sh " curl -sLu ${JENKINS_API_USER}:${JENKINS_API_PSW} \"${lastBuildCommitUrl}\" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' """)
    lastBuildNumber = sh([script:"curl -sLu ${JENKINS_API_USER}:${JENKINS_API_PSW} \"${lastBuildNumberUrl}\"", returnStdout: true]).trim();
}
```

The code above assumes that you can get the git url for the repository, the git branch of the repository you care about, the job url for the "other jenkins job" that you want, and also that you have a non-userid that has an api token that you can use to access the jenkins api from within jenkins.

Comment: could this be done without sh and curl? I'm on Windows, so I would prefer native groovy solution...

Comment: This question has some native groovy for getting api responses and parsing xml: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666321/how-can-i-get-all-build-numbers-of-particular-job-in-jenkins-using-groovy-script?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can add a build description with the commit hash to your builds and then retrieve the description in the other build.

```
stage('Set commit id as a build description') {
    currentBuild.setDescription(sh(script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim())
}
```

and then, you can do:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.Job)
       .filter { it.fullName.equals(params.theOtherJobNameSpecifiedViaParamByTheUser)[0]
       .getBuild(params.buildNoSpecifiedViaParamByTheUser)
       .getDescription()
```

This is not exactly what you were looking for, but I think, this is the most convenient way to achieve what you want.